# Laravel VueJs SPA : should VueJS router routes match with Laravel routes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

The question is pretty simple.

in order to build a Simple Page Application (SPA) with Laravel and VueJS , should all the paths present in router.js ( the file defining paths for SPA) be also present in `web.php` of Laravel ?

For example I am using the source code from [here](https://github.com/tutsplus/code-a-single-page-app-with-laravel-and-vuejs/tree/master/3.6) :

`router.js` inside `resources/assets/js/frontend`  has :

```
export default [

    { path: '/create', component: SubmitTicketFormComponent },
    { path: '/view/:ticketId', name: 'client-view-ticket', component: ViewTicketComponent, props: true }
];
```

But the `web.php` inside `routes` folder has

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin');
});
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
//Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And the `api.php` inside `routes` folder has :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index');
    Route::apiResource('/admin/tickets', 'Admin\TicketsController');
});
Route::apiResource('tickets', 'TicketsController');
```

So what are the rules regarding the path or route declaration for both VueJs and Laravel ?

Comment: Check out my laravel spa package,  https://laravue-spa.wheelmaker.dev its not ready for prime time yet but you can probably get a lot out of looking through it.

Comment: @wheelmaker, I tried to tun the code under directory `Chapter07` from here : https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Full-Stack-Vue.js-2-and-Laravel-5. But the URL `listing/5` showed no rendered content in the place of `router-view` in `App.vue`. Both `router.js` and `web.php` paths and routes match there. Can you take the repo as a standard to make it clear what makes it not to render the mentioned part i,e: whether it is any path related issue or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a SPA and keep some of the Laravel pages you need to have a route like this:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'VueController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

This can be at the end of your routing file, so if it does not match the existing Laravel routes and it will open the Vue SPA and the routing will be handled from there.

Comment: what are the rules regarding the path or route declaration for both VueJs and Laravel ? Should they match ?Which paths should be in `router.js` and which ones should be in `web.php` ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed, no, they do not need to match. Keep your Lravel routes in `web.php` and your SPA routes in `router.js`.

Comment: so I can even have no routes declared inside `web.php` ?

Comment: ' it will open the Vue SPA and the routing will be handled from there. ' - can you elaborate a bit more ? How can a ViewJS path interact with controller ?

Comment: VueJS SPA path  does not need interaction with a controller to display the page. So how will a controller ,method send data to a `.vue` file when there is for all SPA paths  an entry point namely `App.vue` ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed `/{any}` in the route means that all routes not matched will go to that controller where you can load your Vue app.

Comment: Normally a controller method  returns something like `return view('welcome');` to display a page . what will the controller method return so that it can include the `.vue` file at a point  ?

Comment: can you make an answer to my comment at @ wheelmaker  here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305767/laravel-vuejs-spa-should-vuejs-router-routes-match-with-laravel-routes?noredirect=1#comment104838437_59305767 ?